# Call nbtstat command from PHP (64-bit OS)

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm trying to call the `nbtstat` command from PHP using `shell_exec()`. Apparently that doesn't work because I'm using a 64-bit system.

```
echo shell_exec("nbtstat");
```

I've done some research and it seems that the problem is caused by the fact that Windows 64-bit defaults to `\Windows\SysWOW64` as `System32` folder. But `nbtstat` is located in the normal `\Windows\System32` folder.

In normal applications you can call `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` to disable this redirection, but I haven't managed to find this in PHP yet.

Is there a way to actually call these commands from PHP within a 64-bit Operating System?

Answer (score 1):

Add "\Windows\Sysnative" to the end of your environment path.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to grant the `IUSR_<machinename>` user Read & Execute / Read permissions not on the `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\nbtstat.exe` file, but instead on the `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\nbtstat.exe` file.